# Sort an array of int[] via array of double[]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of

```
double[] weights = { 32.0, 32.0, 25.0, 25.0, 30.0, 28.0,
                     12.0, 10.0,  8.0,  8.0, 18.0,  0.0 };
```

I want to sort its corresponding indices `0` through `11` according to a descending sort of `weights`:

```
{ 32.0, 32.0, 30.0, 28.0, 25.0, 25.0, 18.0, 12.0, 10.0, 8.0, 8.0, 0.0 }
```

My desired output, in this case, would be an `int[]`:

```
{ 0, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 }
```

I have added an int[] values to keep track of indices:

```
int[] values = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }
```

Comment: Oneliner in Scala: `weights.zipWithIndex.sortBy(-_._1).map(_._2)`. There is a [library](http://functionaljava.org/) that provides similar abstractions for Java. You can use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a comparable container class, like this

```
class EvanContainer implements Comparable<EvanContainer> {
    double weight;
    int value;

    EvanContainer(double w, int v) { weight = w; value = v; }

    public int compareTo(EvanContainer other) {
        return Double.compare(weight, other.weight);
    } 

}
```

Then you can sort that as normal.

```
EvanContainer[] container = new EvanContainer[weights.length];
for(int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    container[i] = new EvanContainer(weights[i],values[i]);
}

Arrays.sort(container);
```

Comment: this solution, unlike the ones using map (and not multimap) allows repeated values in the double array

Comment: this looks great, glowcoder. unfortunately i'm getting a printout:
EvanContainer@10c832d2
EvanContainer@47808199
EvanContainer@45bc887b
EvanContainer@5ca46701
EvanContainer@2d66a22b
EvanContainer@2d20cc56
EvanContainer@4447393f
EvanContainer@1fff7a1e
EvanContainer@3daa57fb
EvanContainer@7a763f5d
EvanContainer@693a317a
EvanContainer@6b86768e.
Any idea why?

Comment: i believe the issue is in:
container[i] = new EvanContainer(weights[i],values[i]); 
but i may be mistaken

Comment: @Evan the class  I gave you isn't 100% complete. You'll should implement the `toString()` method to get a good printout like that. Something like `public String toString() { return "value=" + value + " weight=" + weight; }` should work.

Comment: that works perfectly! how can i export just the new sorted values to a new int array?

Comment: Well if you iterate over your array of `EvanContainer`s (I hope you called it something better? :D) you can do this: `for(EvanContainer ec : container) newValues[i] = ec.value;`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently and glowcoder's answer is certainly the cleanest and simplest answer. The problem I had with that particular approach, is that it requires you to "box" every element you want to compare. Now if you have a very large number of elements in a primitive array, you don't really want to wrap every element in a object and then use Comparable to sort the wrapped objects because of the performance implications.

So I designed the following solution, which is available in Java as open-source code under the GPL here : http://open.trickl.com/trickl-sort/index.html

The sort algorithms presented allow the specification of a "Permutator". The StandardPermutator just reorders elements in an array as requested (e.g. swaps two elements at different indices). The PairedPermutator also performs the same permutation on a different array (in this case, the indices array).

This way I can use the same efficient sort algorithm on a primitive array and additionally keep track of the index rearrangement without ever boxing the values in the array. That's the theory anyway, I've not done any actual performance comparisons... Either way, I hope the library presented gives a more flexible approach to sorting.

Answer (score 0):

A [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) might be a good backing structure—it keeps your values and indices in paired groups.